# How to have equal distance between xticks in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, xticks

From the below figure, we can see that many data points fall in a very close range. That is why I manually set the sticks, but the problem is all the xticks have equal distance between them.

Can anyone please tell me how can I have an equal distance between xticks? so that we can differentiate between those close values clearly from the figure.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like change to a [log scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html)?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to do.  You place all your ticks close together, one per data point, but then you say you don’t want them close together.  Are you trying to spread the data out or just the ticks?

Comment: I want there should be equal distance between all ticks. You can see that many ticks overlap on the left side. @JodyKlymak

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the two options listed below:

First option to use categorical plot

```
sns.pointplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", ax=ax2) #categorical plot
```

Second option to make x axis as string in your original graph

```
ax.plot(x.astype('str'), y)
```